# Should I create a user authentication or use a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and indecisive as to what I should do.

I am creating a dating website with limited features. Do you recommend I use something like Devise or Clearance for user authentication or should I build my own?

My process will be register > login > pay for membership (using PayPal micropayment system).

There will be 2 levels of users, register and paid register users.  One last login feature will be after user is signed in they can connect to their Facebook. This will just display on profile that user is facebook verified to add more creditability to their account. No FB information will be shared.

I don't mind doing the actual working and learning more since I am new to coding. I just want to hear opinions on if I should build from ground up based on what I said above that I need or if I should just use a plugin.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel. It's really rare that's worth it.

Comment: Who do you trust more to build an auth system - the folks that build devise, sorcery, etc, or yourself?  :)  Kidding aside, if you want to do this for the educational experience, go for it, but if this is for work I would just use a standard package.  Nobody builds their own RDBMS system when MySQL / PostgreSQL / whatever is there.

Comment: This is for my own project. I'm not a freelancer. But I do understand what you mean Dave.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a plugin unless you actually want to create an authentication system.

There's nothing intrinsically *wrong* with re-inventing the wheel, it's just that the work of other wheel makers is better tested, more mature, and widely distributed.

That said, there's nothing that disallows you from using a home-grown simplistic mechanism and switching to a more functional, better known mechanism later. The ease of doing this depends on your implementation, and how tolerant the chosen auth mechanism is of variances from its own patterns.